# Alamofire 4.6.0 does not seem to be sending a POST request

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am trying to send a POST request with Alamofire 4.6.0 and the request is not firing, when I debug it, it shows that Alamofire is building the request but it does not seem like it is sending the request.

This code is nested in a method that has a completion handler.

```
func phoneVerifyStart(Step: Bool, PhoneNumber: String, authCode: String?, completionHandler: @escaping (_ response: Any? ->()){

//Create our request with the users phone number
let jsonData = ["request": ["method": "phoneNumberVerificationStart","id": 1, "params": ["number": "\(PhoneNumber)"] ]]
let urlString = “************************************”


Alamofire.request(requestURL, method: .post, parameters: jsonData, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
    print("here")    
    completionHandler(response)
}
}
```

I am not getting any response at all, I am also not able to hit the "here".
The server does not receive a call from this code so the code is not sending a request at all.

Comment: Your jsonData is a Swift dictionary object.  It's not a JSON object because you haven't JSON-serialize it.

Comment: I am pretty sure the JSONEncoding.default takes the dictionary and turns it into JSON at run time. If I serialize it I run into an error.